# Is Microsoft.AspNetCore no longer available?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I was testing the Asp.NET Core authentication features. The **project.json** is copied from the GitHub exmaple. [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/SocialSample/project.json)

> NU1001 The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel >= 1.0.0-* could not be resolved.

Other dependencies can be successfully resolved. And I also double checked my dnvm version.

The IntelliSense in Visual Studio also shows there is no `Microsoft.AspNetCore...` package in **dependencies**.

So if I want to add

```
app.UseOAuthAuthentication("Google-AccessToken", options =>...);
```

in **Startup.cs**, what is the correct dependency to use?

Comment: Please watch https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements for breaking changes and do a search there to see if you can locate the change you are interested in.

Comment: Wow I didn't know there is a Announcements project. Thanks.

Comment: @Blaise: Are you also using the nightly feed? The Microsoft.AspNetCore.* packages aren't available on the official nuget3 feed (also you need the latest rc2 dnx nightly runtime or dotnet-cli). The feed you should use (at least for dnx) is https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v3/index.json and https://dotnet.myget.org/F/cli-deps/api/v3/index.json this one worked for me for dotnet-cli a few weeks ago

Comment: I was looking at the examples in GitHub. https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/SocialSample/project.json

Comment: That's not answering my question. The `project.json` file contains no information about nuget feeds used. On a project basis it's in `NuGet.Config` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the nightly builds, you need to add the nightly package repositories to do so.

1. First you will need to use the latest rc2 nightly runtime `dnvm upgrade -u latest`. **Beware, it will fail to restore packages *really* often!!**
2. You need to add the proper nuget feeds. The official nuget feed (https://www.nuget.org/api/v2) do not contain this packages, as they are nightly builds and pretty unstable. Official nuget feed only has `rc1-final` packages

   From my experience these feeds worked well for rc2 for me

   - Old (now deprecated) DNX runtime: https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v3/index.json
   - New dotnet-cli tooling: https://dotnet.myget.org/F/cli-deps/api/v3/index.json
3. If you want to try out dotnet-cli you need to install it and follow the instructions in my previous answer on how to run ASP.NET MVC on dotnet-cli found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35528843/455493).

That being said, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel` uses the new naming scheme, which means it's RC2 since `Microsoft.AspNet.*` packages where renamed to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` some time during RC2 cycle.

If you need a stable base to play around, use `rc1-final` and it's versions, as they won't be updates at any time and your package restore won't fail multiple times a week due to upgrade to the runtime or packages.

The samples in the dev branch always target the nightly builds, that's some RC2 nightly build at the time of the writing. You either have use the sample in rc1-final branch or switch to rc2 nightly (runtime and packages) and wait for rc2 to be released (hopefully soon).

You can find the rc1-final version of `project.json` in the [rc1-final tag](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/1.0.0-rc1/samples/SocialSample) or [directly here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/1.0.0-rc1/samples/SocialSample/project.json).